# Enlarge image pixels with opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
cv::Mat gray;
cv::Mat resize;
cv::Mat big;
cv::cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::resize(gray, resize, cv::Size(src.rows/2, src.cols/2));
cv::resize(resize, big, cv::Size(src.rows, src.cols));
cv::Mat clone(resize.rows, resize.cols, CV_8U);

for(int y=0;y<resize.rows;y++){
       for(int x=0;x<resize.cols;x++){
           clone.at<uchar>(y,x) = resize.at<uchar>(y,x);

                               }
                                 }
            cv::imshow("clone", clone);
```

I wrote my code and I have 2 questions
1) How can I enlarge 1 pixel into 4 pixels? and also show them.
2) How can I enlarge every pixels of image into 4 multiply with every pixels of image? (Not to use interpolation)

Edit

[image]

from my image I want to enlarge 1 pixel into 4 pixel.
Then all of pixels image must englarged into bigger image.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use nearest-neighbor "interpolation": `cv::INTER_NEAREST` (or `CV_INTER_NN`) with [`cv::resize()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?#resize):

```
cv::resize(gray, enlarged, cv::Size(gray.cols*2, gray.rows*2), cv::INTER_NEAREST);
```

The nearest-neighbor resizing scheme is not really interpolation. It just chooses the closest pixel in the original. When enlarging by a factor of 2 to each pixel will be duplicated 4 times as in your drawing.

Comment: But I need to enlarge by 1 pixel multiply into 4 pixels then I use command imshow. Best thank.

Comment: cv::resize(gray, enlarged, cv::Size(gray.rows*2, gray.cols*2), cv::INTER_NEAREST);     From this code it not enlarge by not to use interpolation is there another way? to solving this? I need to enlarge 1 pixel by 4 pixel  and the solution must be the image that not smooth.

Comment: I don't understand your question nor your problem. Try providing more detail and an example.

Comment: The answer is correct. "Cutting" a pixel in 4 pixels is typically done by replicating it and the technical term is indeed nearest neighbour interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [Adi Shavit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135862/adi-shavit) is technically **correct**: you have to use *nearest neighbour interpolation* for your task.

What happens however is not that pixels get bigger, but that the image has more pixels. The size of a pixel is fixed (and happens to be indefinite nowadays): it is *really* just a photosite of the screen used to display the image. Yo will have the *feeling* that pixels get bigger when you display the image on screen, because nearest neighbour interpolation simply replicates the original pixels.

Few years ago, you could have assumptions about the pixel size (typically 1/72 inch), but retina screens did move the lines here. Furthermore, some task-oriented raster image format such as Geotiff allowed to embed the physical size of a pixel (i.e., its footprint on the ground) as a metadata in the image file.