# Duplicating pixel values in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have RGB images, e.g. of size 2x2 as follows:

```
[  0,  14, 255,  75, 156, 255;
  45, 255, 234, 236, 141, 255]
```

I would like to duplicate each pixel (all of the RGB channels) 2x2 times and obtain images that look like:

```
[  0,  14, 255,  0, 14, 255,  75, 156, 255, 75, 156, 255;
   0,  14, 255,  0, 14, 255,  75, 156, 255, 75, 156, 255;
  45, 255, 234,  45, 255, 234, 236, 141, 255, 236, 141, 255;
  45, 255, 234,  45, 255, 234, 236, 141, 255, 236, 141, 255  ]
```

In Matlab or Python, I would do this simply by using the `kron` function but I couldn`t figure out how to do it easily in OpenCV C++. Note that this is a trivial example, I would actually like to duplicate each pixel by 16x16 and do it on much bigger images, not 2x2 of course.

Comment: I think `cv::resize` with the interpolation `INTER_NEAREST` will do the trick.  Found a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342543/enlarge-image-pixels-with-opencv) that corroborate with the resize idea. Although, I havent tried/used this interpolation yet.

Comment: Can you please post how you would do that in Matlab?

Comment: Hi @Miki, What do you mean by Matlab? I though your question were how to do it using OpenCV and C++. Anyway, I just tried here and it works. I used the command `cv::resize(m, enlarged, cv::Size(m.rows*20, m.cols*20), 20, 20, cv::INTER_NEAREST);` to resize 20x (so I could see and validate the result).

Comment: @wendelbsilva I was asking OP how he'll do that in Matlab...

Comment: Ops.. my bad. I though you were the Op.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `resize` with nearest neighbor interpolation `INTER_NEAREST`:

**Code:**

```
Mat mInput(2, 2, CV_8UC3),mOutput(4, 4, CV_8UC3);

mInput.at<Vec3b>(0,0)= Vec3b(0,14,255);
mInput.at<Vec3b>(0,1)= Vec3b(75,156,255);
mInput.at<Vec3b>(1,0)= Vec3b(45,255,234);
mInput.at<Vec3b>(1,1)= Vec3b(236,141,255);

cout<<mInput<<"\n";

resize(mInput,mOutput,Size(4,4),0,0,INTER_NEAREST);

cout<<mOutput<<"\n";;
```

**Output**

```
[  0,  14, 255,  75, 156, 255;
  45, 255, 234, 236, 141, 255]
[  0,  14, 255,   0,  14, 255,  75, 156, 255,  75, 156, 255;
   0,  14, 255,   0,  14, 255,  75, 156, 255,  75, 156, 255;
  45, 255, 234,  45, 255, 234, 236, 141, 255, 236, 141, 255;
  45, 255, 234,  45, 255, 234, 236, 141, 255, 236, 141, 255]
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Thanks to @wendelbsilva for pointing this out in the comments.

Comment: I tested with bigger images and bigger resize. This method works ok as long as you provide the correct Size in `resize`. You always learn something new :D  Good call

Comment: Great! I didn't know that `resize` had such an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `kron` function and do as you would do in Matlab and Python. Note that Kronecker product is defined on single channel matrices, so you need to split the planes BGR matrix, apply `kron`, and then merge back.

This below code will produce your exact output:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat kron(const Mat A, const Mat B)
{
    CV_Assert(A.channels() == 1 && B.channels() == 1);

    Mat1d Ad, Bd;
    A.convertTo(Ad, CV_64F);
    B.convertTo(Bd, CV_64F);

    Mat1d Kd(Ad.rows * Bd.rows, Ad.cols * Bd.cols, 0.0);

    for (int ra = 0; ra < Ad.rows; ++ra)
    {
        for (int ca = 0; ca < Ad.cols; ++ca)
        {
            Kd(Range(ra*Bd.rows, (ra + 1)*Bd.rows), Range(ca*Bd.cols, (ca + 1)*Bd.cols)) = Bd.mul(Ad(ra, ca));
        }
    }
    Mat K;
    Kd.convertTo(K, A.type());
    return K;

}

int main()
{
    Mat3d A(2,2);
    A(0, 0) = Vec3d(0, 14, 255);
    A(0, 1) = Vec3d(75, 156, 255);
    A(1, 0) = Vec3d(45, 255, 234);
    A(1, 1) = Vec3d(236, 141, 255);

    cout << "A:" << endl;
    cout << A << endl;

    Mat1d B = Mat1d::ones(2,2);

    cout << "B:" << endl;
    cout << B << endl;

    vector<Mat> planes;
    split(A, planes);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        planes[i] = kron(planes[i], B);
    }

    Mat K;
    merge(planes, K);

    cout << "K:" << endl;
    cout << K << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the [OpenCV Repeat function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga8e9c4ef56a85c58332c63997c10a51d8), it's faster (and more readable) than resize with nearest neighbour.