# Upscale an image but making it look the same

Tags: image, image-processing

I have an image that is 8x8px, and i need it to be 16x16, but I want it too look the exact same. So I want every pixel in the 8x8 version to be 4 pixels, making it 16x16. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64624888/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19342625/)

Answer (score 0):

> I want every pixel in the 8x8 version to be 4 pixels, making it 16x16.

What you are describing is commonly called "nearest neighbor" resampling. Most image editing software has an option for this.

One way to do factor-2 nearest neighbor upscaling is to use the [ImageMagick convert](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) command line program like:

```
convert in8x8.png -scale 200% out16x16.png
```

Or if you have MATLAB and the Image Processing Toolbox, you can do it with [imresize](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) as `imresize(I, 2, 'nearest')`.